# when to leave space ,when not in CSS?

Tags: css

This is ok(without space):

```
li.highlight{
    background:#FF9900 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

This will not work(with space):

```
li .highlight{
    background:#FF9900 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

Why?

Comment: I'm not completely positive, but doesn't the second mean "apply to LI and to any element whose class is 'highlight'". The first one means "apply to LI elements with class set to 'highlight'."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The latter selector won't work because the space implies the relationship (in this case a descendant) between the selectors.

```
li.highlight /* defines an element of 'li' with a classname of 'highlight' */

li .highlight /* defines an element of class 'highlight' that's contained within an li element */

li > .highlight /* as pointed out by Neil (in comments), this would select an element of class highlight that is an immediate child/descendant of an li */
```

I should explain my use of the phrase "won't work." Clearly I used your phrasing, and I did so in error.

It *will* work, it's just that it will select -as explained in the comment- an element that you don't have in your markup.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "immediate descendant," but "li .highlight" selects elements with class "highlight" contained by an li element; "li > .highlight" would be the syntax for selecting immediate children only. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#selector-syntax

Comment: Yeah, your comment for the second selector is incorrect. > selects children (aka immediate descendants), while " " considers all descendants. -1

Comment: +1'd and my thanks, Neil, I've amended the answer. If anyone else could join me in voting up Neil's answer, that'd be ace. =)

Answer (score 3):

First example:

```
<li class="highlight">this will be highlighted</li>
```

Second example:

```
<li class="highlight">
    <span class="highlight">this will be higlighted</span>
    <span>this won't be.</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because space (in a selector) means descend down the DOM to find matching tags, so:

- li.highlight

  - Means **Find any list item with the class name *highlight* and apply this style**
- li .highlight

  - Means **Find any element with the *class name highlight, who's ancestor is a list item*, and apply this style**

Answer (score 2):

spacing is meant to call different elements and not items related to one element. for example *.highlight* is not a separate element. While calling *div table* are all seperate elements

Answer (score 2):

You can think of `li .highlight` as having an implied `*` in it. It is equivalent to `li *.highlight`.

- `li.highlight` matches an `li` element with a class of `highlight`: `<li class="highlight">`.
- `li .highlight` with a space matches an element with class `highlight` which is inside of an `li` (a descendant): for example, the `span` in `<li><strong>OMG <span class="highlight">NO WAY!</span></li>`

Answer (score 1):

Without space you are selecting a li with the class highlight. With the sapce you are selecting a descandant of a li, where the descendant has a class highlight.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you select all li tags with class "highlight". In the second case you select children of li tags with class "highlight".

You should read up on CSS selectors in [the W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html).